# Ubuntu Wireless adapter not found (Ralink Corp. Device [1814: 539a])

Tags: networking, drivers, wireless, ralink

I just switched from Windows 10 to Linux. I am using HP Probook 4540s and Ubuntu 18.04 LTS with Kernel 5.3.0-46-generic x86_64.

I am facing problems with the driver the driver of wireless card.

I am sorry if I have added too much unnecessary information. Thanks in advance.

The output for `iwconfig`:

```
enp4s0    no wireless extensions.
lo        no wireless extensions.
```

There is no output for `rfkill list all`.

The output for `sudo lshw -C network` is

```
  *-network UNCLAIMED       
   description: Network controller
   product: Ralink corp.
   vendor: Ralink corp.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:03:00.0
   version: 00
   width: 32 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress cap_list
   configuration: latency=0
   resources: memory:d0600000-d060ffff
  *-network
   description: Ethernet interface
   product: RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller
   vendor: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd.
   physical id: 0
   bus info: pci@0000:04:00.0
   logical name: enp4s0
   version: 07
   serial: b4:b5:2f:79:e8:59
   size: 1Gbit/s
   capacity: 1Gbit/s
   width: 64 bits
   clock: 33MHz
   capabilities: pm msi pciexpress msix vpd bus_master cap_list ethernet physical tp mii 10bt 10bt-fd 100bt 100bt-fd 1000bt 1000bt-fd autonegotiation
   configuration: autonegotiation=on broadcast=yes driver=r8169 duplex=full firmware=rtl8168e-3_0.0.4 03/27/12 ip=192.168.0.154 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes port=MII speed=1Gbit/s
   resources: irq:17 ioport:2000(size=256) memory:d0404000-d0404fff memory:d0400000-d0403fff
```

The output for `sudo modprobe wl` is

```
modprobe: FATAL: Module wl not found in directory /lib/modules/5.3.0-46-generic
```

Here is the output of `lspci -vvnn | grep -A 9 Network`:

```
03:00.0 Network controller [0280]: Ralink corp. Device [1814:539a]
Subsystem: Hewlett-Packard Company Device [103c:1839]
Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster- SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B- ParErr- DEVSEL=fast >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 19
Region 0: Memory at d0600000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=64K]
Capabilities: <access denied>
Kernel modules: rt2800pci
04:00.0 Ethernet controller [0200]: Realtek Semiconductor Co., Ltd. RTL8111/8168/8411 PCI Express Gigabit Ethernet Controller [10ec:8168] (rev 07)
```

Here is the output for `lsmod`:

```
Module                  Size  Used by
intel_rapl_msr         20480  0
intel_rapl_common      24576  1 intel_rapl_msr
snd_hda_codec_hdmi     57344  1
snd_hda_codec_idt      61440  1
uvcvideo               94208  0
snd_hda_codec_generic    81920  1 snd_hda_codec_idt
x86_pkg_temp_thermal    20480  0
intel_powerclamp       20480  0
videobuf2_vmalloc      20480  1 uvcvideo
coretemp               20480  0
ledtrig_audio          16384  1 snd_hda_codec_generic
videobuf2_memops       20480  1 videobuf2_vmalloc
videobuf2_v4l2         24576  1 uvcvideo
videobuf2_common       49152  2 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo
videodev              208896  3 videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
mc                     53248  4 videodev,videobuf2_v4l2,uvcvideo,videobuf2_common
snd_hda_intel          53248  6
kvm                   655360  0
irqbypass              16384  1 kvm
crct10dif_pclmul       16384  1
crc32_pclmul           16384  0
ghash_clmulni_intel    16384  0
snd_intel_nhlt         20480  1 snd_hda_intel
cryptd                 24576  1 ghash_clmulni_intel
intel_cstate           20480  0
intel_rapl_perf        20480  0
i915                 1937408  29
snd_hda_codec         131072  4 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec_idt
snd_hda_core           90112  5 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_codec_idt
drm_kms_helper        180224  1 i915
snd_hwdep              20480  1 snd_hda_codec
snd_pcm               102400  4 snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_hda_core
joydev                 28672  0
snd_seq_midi           20480  0
snd_seq_midi_event     16384  1 snd_seq_midi
hp_wmi                 16384  0
input_leds             16384  0
serio_raw              20480  0
snd_rawmidi            36864  1 snd_seq_midi
sparse_keymap          16384  1 hp_wmi
wmi_bmof               16384  0
snd_seq                69632  2 snd_seq_midi,snd_seq_midi_event
drm                   491520  18 drm_kms_helper,i915
i2c_algo_bit           16384  1 i915
snd_seq_device         16384  3 snd_seq,snd_seq_midi,snd_rawmidi
jmb38x_ms              24576  0
snd_timer              36864  2 snd_seq,snd_pcm
hp_accel               28672  0
fb_sys_fops            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
syscopyarea            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysfillrect            16384  1 drm_kms_helper
sysimgblt              16384  1 drm_kms_helper
lis3lv02d              24576  1 hp_accel
memstick               20480  1 jmb38x_ms
snd                    86016  23 snd_hda_codec_generic,snd_seq,snd_seq_device,snd_hda_codec_hdmi,snd_hwdep,snd_hda_intel,snd_hda_codec,snd_timer,snd_pcm,snd_hda_codec_idt,snd_rawmidi
input_polldev          20480  1 lis3lv02d
soundcore              16384  1 snd
hp_wireless            16384  0
lpc_ich                24576  0
mac_hid                16384  0
sch_fq_codel           20480  2
rt2800pci              16384  0
rt2800mmio             20480  1 rt2800pci
rt2800lib             126976  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00pci              16384  1 rt2800pci
rt2x00mmio             16384  2 rt2800mmio,rt2800pci
rt2x00lib              61440  5 rt2x00mmio,rt2x00pci,rt2800mmio,rt2800pci,rt2800lib
mac80211              778240  3 rt2x00pci,rt2x00lib,rt2800lib
cfg80211              688128  2 rt2x00lib,mac80211
compat                 16384  2 mac80211,cfg80211
eeprom_93cx6           16384  1 rt2800pci
libarc4                16384  1 mac80211
parport_pc             40960  0
ppdev                  24576  0
lp                     20480  0
parport                53248  3 parport_pc,lp,ppdev
ip_tables              32768  0
x_tables               40960  1 ip_tables
autofs4                45056  2
r8169                  81920  0
ahci                   40960  1
sdhci_pci              45056  0
libahci                32768  1 ahci
realtek                20480  1
psmouse               151552  0
cqhci                  28672  1 sdhci_pci
sdhci                  57344  1 sdhci_pci
wmi                    32768  2 hp_wmi,wmi_bmof
video                  49152  1 i915
```

and finally the output of `dkms status` is following:

```
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 4.15.0-96-generic, x86_64: installed
rtlwifi-new, 0.6, 5.3.0-46-generic, x86_64: installed
```

Settings > Wifi shows "No Wi-fi Adopter found".